# Symfony 2 asset, check if file exists performance

Tags: php, symfony

on symfony 2, using `Twig` you can use the `asset()` function to link an image in the way
 `{{ asset('path_to_the_image') }}`, now if the file does not exists then the src of the file keeps the same,

Thinking about that, I was tempted to create another Twig function on my `TwigExtensions`, in order to check the file existence, in order to do the following, If the file exists then I will use the given url and if does not exists then I will change the result of the function to a default image that I will use as a not_image image.
The motivation for this function is to always show an image to the user.

Now, my question.

I can't figure out the performance issues with this approach because I will check the file twice, the first time to check if exists and the other time is the request that asks for the file. And the usual thing to do is to put the asset address and in case the file does not exists replace it with some default file using javascript.

I will use php's file_exists function, and on the manual I have read that is very inexpensive and that in case that the file indeed exists the result is cached to avoid performance issues.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Just use file_get_contents. If it eventually turns out to be a problem, cache it, use a registry/index of existing files. But my guess is by the time that becomes a performance issue, simply adding a faster server is the quickest and chepast solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file_exists` triggers a read access to your file system (or, even just the FS metadata). This is very inexpensive indeed. Keep in mind that, when running a Symfony application, you’re usually accessing hundreds of PHP files alone.

The result of `file_exists` is cached indeed, but only while during the execution of a script. So, if you call `file_exists` several times within one script execution (and don’t call `clearstatcache` in between), the result is cached. If you call the script again later, PHP will look for the file again.

---

However, if you *really* worry about performance, you shouldn’t check for the files’ existence “on the fly”, but instead create a Symfony command that checks if all linked assets are valid during building or deployment.

This command would basically render all pages, and your custom asset function would, instead of returning a dummy image, throw an exception. This way, you only need to check once, during deployment, if all assets are valid.

Comment: Thanks, I can do it with a command, but the assets I mean to check are images uploaded by users.  I will mark the answer as correct.